# read data form xml to list

Tags: python, xml

I have a python script that reads data from an xml file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


MAX_VALUE = 20
PATH_IN = "sweep.xml"


tree = ET.parse(PATH_IN)
root = tree.getroot()

projects = [""]*MAX_VALUE
designs = [""]*MAX_VALUE
params = [""]*MAX_VALUE

for i, project in enumerate(root):
    projects[i] = project
    print(project.get('name'))
    for u, design in enumerate(project):
        designs[u] = design
        print(design.get('name'))
        for x, param in enumerate(design):
            params[x] = param
            print(param.get('name'))
            for x, info in enumerate(param):
                print(info.text)

raw_input()
```

Here's the xml

```
<xml>
    <project name="testProj">
        <design name="des1">
            <param name="mag_d">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>1</start>
                <stop>5</stop>
                <step>1</step>
            </param>
            <param name="mag_x">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>2</start>
                <stop>7</stop>
                <step>1</step>
            </param>
            <param name="mag_y">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>1</start>
                <stop>2</stop>
                <step>0.1</step>
            </param>
        </design>
        <design name="des2">
            <param name="mag_d">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>1</start>
                <stop>5</stop>
                <step>1</step>
            </param>
            <param name="mag_x">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>2</start>
                <stop>7</stop>
                <step>1</step>
            </param>
            <param name="mag_y">
                <value>3mm</value>
                <start>1</start>
                <stop>2</stop>
                <step>0.1</step>
            </param>
        </design>
    </project>
</xml>
```

What I want to do now is to add the information I'm reading into a list. It should look somthing like this:

```
Input=[['testProj','des1',[['mag_d',[1,2,3]],['mag_x',[2,3,4]]]], ['testProj','des2'[['mag_d',[1,2,3]],['mag_x',[2,3,4]]]]]
```

I don't really know how to create a list like that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This seems a fairly simple problem, which makes me think that you've tried something which didn't work as expected. Post your attempt to create such a list, and we'll be able to help you out much better

Comment: I tried to save the information in the lists projects, designs and params and use them as values to create the bigger list. Since that dind't work out quite well i've scraped that attempt

Comment: Looking at the list that you say you want, to me it doesn't look very useful in that it wouldn't be very accessible. It seems it would be better to model it as a dict or JSON document. Unless of course you've a very good reason to make it look like a list.

Comment: I'm working with a script that needs it's input like that, what I'm trying to do is add an xml reader so the list can get it's input via xml files(because manually adding the information into the script is stupid)

Comment: Why `Input` has two `testProj`. Do you mean `[['testProj', ['des1', [...]], ['des2', [...]]]]`?

Comment: no, I want it exactly as I've written. I can understand that it looks strange, I think so too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a list at each level and append what you read into it. At the end of each level, append the list to the outer-level list.

```
lst_lvl1 = [] # Top level list

for i, project in enumerate(root):
    projects[i] = project

    print(project.get('name'))
    lst_lvl1.append(project.get('name')) # Append to the top level list

    lst_lvl2 = [] # Create an empty 2nd level list

    for u, design in enumerate(project):
        designs[u] = design
        print(design.get('name'))
        lst_lvl2.append(design.get('name')) # Append to the 2nd level list

        lst_lvl3 = [] # Create a 3rd level list...
        for x, param in enumerate(design):
            params[x] = param
            print(param.get('name'))
            lst_lvl3.append(param.get('name'))
            lst_lvl4 = []
            for x, info in enumerate(param):
                print(info.text)
                lst_lvl4.append(info.text)
            lst_lvl3.append(lst_lvl4) # At the end of level 4, append what you got to the level-3 list
        lst_lvl2.append(lst_lvl3) # At the end of level 3, append what you got to the level-2 list... etc
    lst_lvl1.append(lst_lvl2)

print lst_lvl1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another version w/o building lists.
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
PATH_IN = "sweep.xml"

tree = ET.parse(PATH_IN)

def convert(root):
    for p in root.iter('project'):
        yield p.get('name')
        for d in p.iter('design'):
            yield  d.get('name')
            for e in d.iter('param'):
                yield [e.attrib['name'], [p.text for p in e]]

it = convert(tree.getroot())
import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(it))
```

On OP input gives.

```
['testProj',
 'des1',
 ['mag_d', ['3mm', '1', '5', '1']],
 ['mag_x', ['3mm', '2', '7', '1']],
 ['mag_y', ['3mm', '1', '2', '0.1']],
 'des2',
 ['mag_d', ['3mm', '1', '5', '1']],
 ['mag_x', ['3mm', '2', '7', '1']],
 ['mag_y', ['3mm', '1', '2', '0.1']]]
```

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer. However, your output is different from OP's ouput, though OP's output is very weird.

Comment: I struggled to understand what the true output should be - but thought that it'd be easy enough for OP to jiggle it about.